# Retraining InceptionV3: Does not converge with input dimensions 299x299

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network, keras-layer

I'm using Keras with pretrained weights for the Conv Layers and want to train only the dense layer.

The model performs as expected when I use input dimensions 150x150 or 224x224 but does not converge with 299x299 (train loss increases, train & validation accuracy remains flat equivalent to random guess).

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

solved - learning rate needs to be adjusted depending on input size in CNN